# Copy within pod curl to kubernetes dir

Tags: curl, kubernetes, kubectl

Helllo does any one have an idea and can help here ?
- I can not run a for me very complicated curl command i have some troubles to understand why its not working

I try to copy data via curl into a Wordpress Directory - at a POD from Kubernetes

```
kubectl exec $WPPOD -- curl --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: *******' 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/*****/repository/files/infrastructure%2Fwordpress%2Fdeploy%2Fall-in-one-wp-migration-unlimited-extension%2Ezip/raw?ref=Add_WP_MySQL' > /var/www/html/wp-content/ai1wm-backups                                     
sh: 7: cannot create  /var/www/html/wp-content/ai1wm-backups -: Directory nonexistent
```

Also from within the cube this is not working

```
# curl --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: Z7-RByYpUJcnWU_STpuz' 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/14628452/repository/files/infrastructure%2Fwordpress%2Fdeploy%2Fall-in-one-wp-migration-unlimited-extension%2Ezip/raw?ref=Add_WP_MySQL' > /var/www/html/wp-content/ai1wm-backups/all-in-one-wp-migration-unlimited-extension.zip -O -J -L
sh: 3: cannot create  /var/www/html/wp-content/ai1wm-backups/all-in-one-wp-migration-unlimited-extension.zip -O -J -L: Directory nonexistent
```

But if i check the directory within the cube it is fine

```
# cd /var/www/html/wp-content/ai1wm-backups
# ls
index.php  web.config
```

Thanks to the helpful input i have now a solution

```
kubectl exec $WPPOD -- curl --fail --output /var/www/html/wp-content/ai1wm-backups/all-in-one-wp-migration-unlimited-extension.zip --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: *******' 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/*****/repository/files/infrastructure%2Fwordpress%2Fdeploy%2Fall-in-one-wp-migration-unlimited-extension%2Ezip/raw?ref=Add_WP_MySQL'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two pieces of bad shell going on here:

The first one is because the redirection is happening **on your machine**. The second is because everything after the `>` is a filename, but you have included random arguments to `curl` in them.

To solve the first one, package the whole command into a shell literal:

```
kubectl exec $WPPOD -- sh -c "curl --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: *******' 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/*****/repository/files/infrastructure%2Fwordpress%2Fdeploy%2Fall-in-one-wp-migration-unlimited-extension%2Ezip/raw?ref=Add_WP_MySQL' > /var/www/html/wp-content/ai1wm-backups"
```

I would even go so far as to say "don't use redirection," since if you inform `curl` of the output file, and add `--fail` to it, then it will avoid writing to that file on server error, which isn't true when using a shell redirection: the shell **will** create that file, no matter what, possibly making it empty; thus:

```
kubectl exec $WPPOD -- curl --fail --output /var/www/html/wp-content/ai1wm-backups --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: *******' 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/*****/repository/files/infrastructure%2Fwordpress%2Fdeploy%2Fall-in-one-wp-migration-unlimited-extension%2Ezip/raw?ref=Add_WP_MySQL'
```

For the second problem, it's a simple matter of re-arranging the arguments to be compliant with shell syntax:

```
curl  -O -J -L --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: Z7-RByYpUJcnWU_STpuz' 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/14628452/repository/files/infrastructure%2Fwordpress%2Fdeploy%2Fall-in-one-wp-migration-unlimited-extension%2Ezip/raw?ref=Add_WP_MySQL' > /var/www/html/wp-content/ai1wm-backups/all-in-one-wp-migration-unlimited-extension.zip
```

Although in that case, you have conflicting `curl` behaviors: [the `-O` option](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-O) is going to write out the file *in the current directory*, so your shell redirect is only going to receive any messages written by `curl`, and *not* the content of that URL

All of this has nothing to do with kubernetes, or a directory, or a copy, and those tags should be removed.

Comment: Thank you, i removed the flags as well however i did think that it might have been related to the fact that i access the Kubernetes POD. Which might did a little difference. I also had to slightly change your command .